# rails 3.2 devise google authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have problem with authentication through devise + google. I have local application written in Ruby on Rails 3.2. I was following devise docs to make this authentication to works:

```
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview
```

So here is my users omniauth controller located in app/controllers/users

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
 def google_oauth2
  @user = User.find_for_google_oauth2(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)
   if @user.persisted?
    flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Google"
    sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
   else
    session["devise.google_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    redirect_to new_user_registration_url
   end
  end
end
```

My routes:

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
```

in my devise.rb initializer:

```
require "omniauth-google-oauth2"
config.omniauth :google_oauth2,   "ClientID", "SecretId", { access_type: "offline", approval_prompt: "" }
```

My user model:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable

  def self.find_for_google_oauth2(access_token, signed_in_resource=nil)
   data = access_token.info
   user = User.where(:email => data["email"]).first
   unless user
    user = User.create(email: data["email"], password: Devise.friendly_token[0,20])
   end
   user
  end
```

I don't know why this is not working. Maybe I'm doing something wrong with generating oauth clientid in google?
I generate my google app clientid and secret like in the following tutorial:
http://richonrails.com/articles/google-authentication-in-ruby-on-rails
Edit: I forgot to show what error I have:
when i click my link:

```
<%= link_to "Login via Google account", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:google_oauth2), :class => "btn btn-inverse btn-large" %>
```

i have the following addres in browser :

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=487629202871.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fusers%2Fauth%2Fgoogle_oauth2%2Fcallback&state=68a65048cca9ccb61a31d2a048bf9ef03d25ebe4a11d77ca&access_type=offline&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile
```

and my error looks like this:
[image]

Comment: What is exactly the problem? What is the error being thrown when you try to login?

Comment: seems like you should have put the shell output of the server